# How to auto-generate unique_rowId with Fluent Migrator in CockroachDB?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, cockroachdb, fluent-migrator

I'm using Fluent Migrator in NET 6.

I'm trying to set an unique_rowId to an int64 column.  On cockroach DB, I would use

`Create table x (version INT NOT NULL DEFAULT unique_rowid())`

With fluent migrator, I cannot find a method to do the above.

I have tried this:
`Create.Table("x").WithColumn("version").AsInt165().NotNullable().WithDefaultValue(SystemMethods.NewGuid)`

but this fails because SystemMethods.NewGuid (and related, SystemMethods.NewSequentialId) both returns a GUID, and the column is an int type.

Is it possible to do this with fluent migrator?

Comment: As a quick workaround. Is there any chance that you could run the raw DDL statement instead of constructing the statement that way? I suspect it requires some work on the adapter.

Comment: @RCX I know there is a workaround approach by just running the raw sql statements, but I asked this question to see if it is possible to do it in this more simple way.

Comment: Fluent Migrator does not provide a built-in method to generate unique row IDs of type INT64.
However, you can achieve the desired functionality by using a custom SQL statement in your migration script.

Comment: I believe I found the answer. We can use the .Identity method to generate unique row IDs:  ```Create.Table("x").WithColumn("version").Identity();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we can use `Create.Table("x").WithColumn("version").Identity()` to generate unique_rowid of type int.